# How do you download SQLite for Xcode through the terminal on mac

Tags: xcode, sqlite, terminal

The problem I am facing is for some reason when i try and pod install the same thing comes up everytime:

Analyzing dependencies
env: illegal option -- u
usage: env [-i] [name=value ...] [utility [argument ...]]
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
env: illegal option -- u
usage: env [-i] [name=value ...] [utility [argument ...]]
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

Before anyone comments, I did put pod 'SQLite' correct in the Podfile. The only problem is what comes up when I try Installing the pod. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been struggling to get sqlite into my Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this pod work: https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift

from there, once you open up the workspace you just import it into the the files you need it in?

Comment: Sorry the was assuming you were using swift@

Comment: nope i used the cocoapods verison caus ep with the error i said before